# Sqs Queue Creation

Tags: java, asynchronous, synchronous, amazon-sqs

Currently i'm creating SQS queue using buffered async sqs client. Once i have the queue URL, i'm using this url for all - send, receive and delete message operations using java AWS SDK.

Now i have a change, which should make async send messages, and sync receive messages, so I created two separate clients for both async & sync.

Now my question is do we have to create separate queue URL for both (sync & async) or same queueURL be used (created from async client) for async & sync operations?

Comment: To clarify the question, are you sending to and receiving from the same queue?  If so, what leads you to the conclusion that the queue URL would be (or even *could* be) different?

Comment: Yes, i'm sending and receiving to the same queue. The reason i had question was, due to the creation of queue using buffered async sqs client (bufferedAsyncClient.createQueue() method.

Comment: The queue will stay the same across Async and sync client.  The only difference is in the client execution and hence you can use the same queueURL for async and sync operations.